# What does M7 mean w.r.t Qualcomm?

Tags: android-log, chipset, qualcomm

I'm trying to figure out a requirement document which frequently mentions this "Qualcomm M7". What is it?

Comment: which document?

Comment: A requirement document given to me to implement certain features,which has certain objectives mentioned.

Comment: Then you should probably ask the one who gave you the document to be more specific.

Comment: Even I'm getting the same feeling now. Thanks for your time. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Qualcomm M7 refers to a audio processor.